# Datomic - Dynamic Query Functions

Tags: clojure, datomic

I was surprised that this didn't work:

```
(d/q '[:find [?e ...]
         :in $ ?field ?op ?value
         :where [?e ?field ?x]
                [(?op ?x ?value)]
         ]
       db
       :my/field
       >
       10))
```

If I remove the op and explicitly code in > in the where clause it works.  Can I not use input parameters to refer to core clojure functions?  Would a rule help?  Or would I need to build up the entire query at runtime using quoting/unquotinq?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defn invoke [f & args] (apply f args))

(d/q '[:find [?e ...]
       :in $ ?field ?op ?value
       :where 
       [?e ?field ?x]
       [(myapp.utils.datomic/invoke ?op ?x ?value)]]
  db :my/field > 10)
```